# Undefined variable but exists and can't find mysqli code

Tags: php, variables, mysqli, undefined

I get these errors after trying to make my code more secure:

> Notice: Undefined variable: db in .../init.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in .../init.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: db in .../init.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in .../init.php on line 10

And this is the code I use:

```
require 'database/connection.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
session_start();

function makeSafe($safe)
{
    $safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $safe);
    return $safe;
}
```

The $db variable is defined in connection.php so it should work right?
And for some reason it's doesn't recognize the mysqli I use in connection.php

```
$host = '...';
$username = '...';
$password = '...';
$dbnaam = '...';
$db_error1 = '...';
$db_error2 = '...';

// Verbinden met Databaseserver
$db=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbnaam) or die($db_error1);

// Verbinden met Database
mysqli_select_db($db, $dbnaam) or die($db_error2);
```

And this has always worked just fine for me.
So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You should read about variable scopes :)

Comment: @RobertRozas sometimes it is so obvious I just cannot see it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable scope problem. Try this:

```
function makeSafe($safe)
{
    global $db;
    $safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $safe);
    return $safe;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I really did not see that

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeSafe($safe)
{
    global $db;
    $safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $safe);
    return $safe;
}
```

or

```
function makeSafe($db,$safe)
{
    $safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $safe);
    return $safe;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach might be like this:

External file

```
<?php
$host = '...';
$username = '...';
$password = '...';
$dbnaam = '...';
$db_error1 = '...';
$db_error2 = '...';

// Verbinden met Databaseserver
$db=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbnaam) or die($db_error1);

// Verbinden met Database
mysqli_select_db($db, $dbnaam) or die($db_error2);

return $db;
```

Main file:

```
<?php

$db = require('database/connection.php');

... the rest of the code ...
```

Note that to use $db in the function, you must use the `global` keyword.